# Protractor tests stop working when opening a component that has an ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

We use the ag-grid in different parts of our site and with protractor tests where a test opens a component that contains the ag-grid the test freezes and nothing happens anymore. The test case is not being completed.
This happens as soon as the ag-grid is getting initialized. If I remove the grid, then the test case continues fine. This behavior is the same in every location where we're using the ag-grid.

Is this an issue or what else could be wrong here?

Comment: Is the grid loading a lot of data? do you see the grid at all in the browser during the test?

Comment: It does not matter if the grid is loading any data or not. In one case it is empty from the beginning and in another the grid loads data. In both cases the protractor test freezes.

Comment: The problem goes away if I set browser.ignoreSynchronization=true before the component that contains the ag-grid gets created. Is this necessary because the ag-grid-ng2 uses a non angular ag-grid underneath?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way around this, but I can tell you its related to the `setTimeout` underneath the hood. I wound up using `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`, and then doing specific Waits with `ExpectedConditions.presenceOf`. Very sloppy and hopefully ag-grid fixes this at somepoint.